# Why doesn't it stick to the top completely when position: fixed?

Tags: html, css

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .content {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
  }
```

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```
````

`positon: fixed` does not cling to the top when applied.

I don't think there are any elements, so I think I should stick up completely, why not?

https://jsfiddle.net/9gqcxLn0/

Comment: i ran your fiddle and the content is clinged to top without any margin

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue other than you never told it where it was supposed to fix to.  You likely wanted a top: 0 in the style, but it should remain fixed from where it was located without it, I believe.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

main {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  abcdefghijk
  <div class="content"></div>
  12345678901234567890
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .content {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
```

you should use top:0